# Google Apps Script Email me when new submission where sample question 3 is yes only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im having difficulty sorting this out. Ive surfed quite a few scripts to see if i could rework but i have no success yet.

I have a sheet where data is submitted by Google Form. Rather than using the built-in option to receive email for every new submission, I would like to only get emails on new submissions where cell E [Sample Question 3] has value "Yes" in it. This will aid me to focus on responses that desire feedback from me.

if possible email should have message "[Email Address] has submitted the following feedback, [Sample Question 4]" and a link to sheet. I have included some sample data as to how the sheet looks for reference.

Please and thank you for guidance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv42f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Wrap your email code with this

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  if(e.values[4] == "Yes") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.values[1],"Subject",`Answer To Question 4: ${e.values[5]}` );
  }
}
```

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

The use of ranges like "B:B" leads to results like the below example reveals:

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}

9:06:45 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:06:44 PM  Info    [["COL1"],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""]]
9:06:46 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

This is what column A of Sheet0 looks like:

| COL1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
| 20 |

This is a better way:

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues()
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}

Execution log
9:11:49 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:11:48 PM  Info    [["COL1"],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]]
9:11:50 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

No nulls at the bottom

Comment: thank you so much. i could use a bit more guidance as well. So i started with this snippet of script. I believe i need to first grab and store values correct? function sendEmail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var userRange = sheet.getRange('B:B') 

}

Comment: You don't need to store the values.  They are getting stored in the linked sheet before the onFormSubmit trigger even fires. The next time you use a range like ("B:B") to getValues() just look at the bottom of the data in the debugger.

Comment: ok so for my needs for this paticular task, i dont need to store values. is all that i need, the onsubmit function provided before?